# Removing duplicates in lines using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geometry, differences

I have a new polyline and need to remove duplicating parts from it. New polyline is compared to other polylines stored in PostGIS table.

I have a query that removes duplicates from line ***newTrack*** comparing it to ***existTrack***.

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Difference(newTrack.newGeo::geometry, existTrack.existGeo::geometry))
FROM (SELECT geography as newGeo
    FROM binndr_road
    WHERE id = 39267) as newTrack,
    (SELECT geography as existGeo
    FROM binndr_road
    WHERE id = 39274) as existTrack;
```

But I have no idea how to compare ***newTrack*** with all lines stored in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Union the Existing Tracks like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Difference(newTrack.newGeo::geometry, existTrack.existGeo::geometry))
FROM
(
    SELECT geography as newGeo
    FROM binndr_road
    WHERE id = 39267
) as newTrack,
(
    SELECT ST_UNION(geography) as existGeo
    FROM binndr_road
    WHERE id != 39267
) as existTrack;
```