# Removing duplicates from string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, string, remove, duplicates

In QGIS 3.18 in a shapefile attribute table, I have some fields with concatenated values (with commas `,` as the delimiter).  Some of the values are duplicate, and I would like to remove them.

For example, if an attribute value is `37.3,37.8,44.A2,37.3,37.31,` I'd like an expression that will catch the two instances of `37.3` and remove one of them (without removing the instance of `37.31` which is a different value).

I have not found a simple SQL expression that can do this in the Field calculator, though I am a relative beginner at SQL and Python.

On this site, there are similar questions:

- [Removing duplicates from field using ArcPy with ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186215/removing-duplicates-from-field-using-arcpy-with-arcmap)
- [Removing duplicates in lines using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224557/removing-duplicates-in-lines-using-postgis)
- [Removing duplicate strings from field with Field Calculator in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314108/removing-duplicate-strings-from-field-with-field-calculator-in-arcmap)

but they are rather old, not for QGIS, and ever-so-slightly out of my league (perhaps the formulas are adaptable, but I'm not sure how).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this expression with the Field calculator to create a new field with duplicates deleted (only distinct values remain). `"text"` is the field name where the initial string is:

```
array_to_string(array_distinct(string_to_array("text")))
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and works for what I need.  Thanks @Babel.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention SQL, here's a PostgreSQL approach to this issue:

```sql
WITH yourvalues AS (
    SELECT
        '37.3,37.8,44.A2,37.3,37.31' AS attributefield
    )

SELECT
    DISTINCT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(attributefield,',')) AS unique_attributes
FROM
    yourvalues
```

Result:

> unique_attributes
> 37.31
> 44.A2
> 37.8
> 37.3

Result without using DISTINCT:

> attributes
> 37.3
> 37.8
> 44.A2
> 37.3
> 37.31

The `yourvalues` CTE doubles as the field in your table. The `SELECT` query first converts that attribute from a string to an array by using `,` as a delimiter, and then [`UNNEST`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_unnest-function.php)s that array and selects [`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/) (i.e. unique) values from the unnested array. You can use this kind of logic in any SQL variant, or the QGIS expression calculator.

Comment: You can use this syntax in either the DB Manager or the Expression calculator.  But why not use a proper backend for your data?

Comment: Thank you @Encomium, I will investigate this possibility.